# Finding a specific string in array of strings

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, for-loop, indexof

In an array of strings, a loop returns `false` if it finds that one of the strings is not what we are looking for.

If it doesn't find an unmatching string, the array is correct and it should return `true`. It keeps returning `false` even when the array has no "mistakes"

I have tried using `indexOf`, for loop and while loops, all of them unsuccessful.

```
function brackets() {
    var testArr = ['()', '{}', '()']

    /* Method 1 --- returns false even when the parenthesis are ok, I guess
    it's because the indexOf only searches for the first element that matches 
    the criteria */

    if (testArr.indexOf("()") == -1 || testArr.indexOf("{}") == -1 ||
        testArr.indexOf("[]") == -1) {
        return false
    } else {
        return true
    }

    /* Method 2 --- for loop. Same story, returns false, even when all   
    testArr[i] === any of the cases and none of them is !==, it behaves as if it was 
    false. I'm not sure why */

    for (i = 0; i < testArr.length; i++) {
        if (testArr[i] !== "()" || testArr[i] !== "{}" || testArr[i] !== "[]") {
            return false
        }
    }
    return true
}

brackets()
```

Comment: `testArr.indexOf("[]")` clearly fails, and as it's a logical OR it returns false if any of them fail ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the second method you can use an AND operator to solve this problem.

```
function brackets() {
var testArr = ['()', '{}', '()'];

/* Method 2 --- for loop. Same story, returns false, even when all   
testArr[i] === any of the cases and none of them is !==, it behaves as if it was 
false. I'm not sure why */

for (i = 0; i < testArr.length; i++) {
    if (testArr[i] !== "()" && testArr[i] !== "{}"  && testArr[i] !== "[]") {
        return false;
    }
}
return true;
}

brackets();
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your array to : `var testArr = ['()', '{}', '[]']`

Since you do

```
 if (testArr.indexOf("()") == -1 || testArr.indexOf("{}") == -1 ||
        testArr.indexOf("[]") == -1)
```

Then even if one of these parenthesis is absent from the array, the condition will return false.

Comment: @vsl0610: but the array in your example clearly has that mistake that it doesn't contain `[]`? If you have problems with "an array that contains no mistakes and still returns false", then you should provide code that demonstrates that case.

Answer (score 0):

You've created an array with

```
var testArr = ['()', '{}', '()']
```

so if you need to test the string you need to test the 2-d array

```
if (testArr[0].indexOf("()") == -1
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
var testArr = ['()', '{}', '()'];

if(testArr.some(function(e){ return /(){}/g.test(e) })){
   console.log("found");
} else {
   console.log("not found");   
}
```

Finding all instances of "()" and "{}"

https://jsfiddle.net/dhoh1932/1/